# Por qué devuelve 3 índices?

Tags: javascript

En el método filter() de los Array de javascript, filter recibe 4 argumentos en el orden de:

```
(elemento,indice,array,contexto)
```

Pero si quiero mostrar los índices de un elemento con 4 de length , solo me muestra 3 indices , por qué?

```js
var b = [4,3,2,1];
var c = b.filter(function(a,b){
  return b;
});
console.log(`El largo es: ${b.length} , pero me devuelve [${c}] indices..`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Para entender este comportamiento hay que recordar que para el método [filter(callback)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

> La función callback indica la regla para realizar el filtrado y debe
>   regresar un valor `verdadero` o `falso`, **si el valor es verdadero ese
>   elemento se añade al arreglo resultado**, en caso contrario es **omitido**.

Es lo que está pasando al encontrar el indice `0` en JS es igual a `falso`, esto se podría comprobar con un arreglo usando el método `filter` para mostrar los valores *(solo para ejemplo)* , pero el primer valor será `false` y el último `0` por lo tanto no los agregará al `array` resultante.

```js
var b = [false,4,3,2,1,0];
var c = b.filter(function(x){
  return x;
});
console.log(c);
```

También recordar que para imprimir los indices podría emplear simplemente [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

```
console.log(Object.keys(b));
```